# List of fixed size Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Is it possible to create a List of arrays(with fixed size) in Java?

I have tried these methods and they both give me a syntax error:

```
List<int[]> failedParameters = new ArrayList<int[3]>();
List<int[]> failedParameters = new ArrayList<new int[3]>();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not with fixed size, no. The best you could do is `new ArrayList<int[]>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Java Map of fixed-length array values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7524499/how-to-create-java-map-of-fixed-length-array-values)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't specify the array length as a Java *type*. However, you can wrap arrays in your own type. I'll let you decide if that is really practical (in case you have dozens of array lengths that you want to support):

```
class Int3 {
    // Use final to indicate that the array length will remain unchanged
    final int[] array = new int[3];
}

List<Int3> failedParameters = new ArrayList<Int3>();
```

Of course, if you go this far, why not just create an int-tuple of degree 3?

```
class Int3 {
    int v1;
    int v2;
    int v3;
}

List<Int3> failedParameters = new ArrayList<Int3>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method. It will not allow you to change the collection size (no add()/remove() operations).

```
List<> unmodiffableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(oListeRet);
```